# Android Navigation Drawer with Page Sliding tab Strip

Tags: android, navigation, sliding, drawer

I'm trying to use Android Navigation Drawer with Page (Pager) Sliding tab Strip (https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip), but i couldn't make it work. I'm using android studio. I made the imports in main project, and doesn't show any error, but when i run into a device (virtual or real) get this error:

```
05-22 10:38:20.200    1434-1434/com.webileapps.navdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.webileapps.navdrawer, PID: 1434
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.webileapps.navdrawer/com.webileapps.navdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webileapps.navdrawer.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webileapps.navdrawer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webileapps.navdrawer-1, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webileapps.navdrawer.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webileapps.navdrawer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webileapps.navdrawer-1, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, thoughts?

Comment: Are you using fragments within the tabs?

Comment: To be honest I would not use that library. I would make the Navigation drawer and add https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip as your tabs.

Comment: Actually i was, i guess. But even changing anything (original library), i got this... @EugeneH , how do i would do that? With the SAME files i could run at Eclipse... Too weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also trying  to implement it and got the same  error .After lot of effort I was able to run it but received the similar error as you have received .
I resolved the issue by
1:Close and start your eclipse .
2: copying the v4 jar of main project in all the library projects and deleting the existing ones . 
The error comes due to mismatch of supportv4jar. Make all the supportv4jar of same version 
3:after that Delete the gen and bin folder and clean the project  and run .